# Reprojecting basemap layers in ArcMap without slowing down zoom and pan options?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, performance

I am using ArcGIS 10.5.1 on a high processing computer. I have 4768 data points that I am required to zoom into and pan around to determine their composition.

They are projected in `NAD 83 CSRS Statistics Canada Lambert` and must stay in this projection.

When I reproject the basemap to this projection, it significantly slows down the ability to zoom in and out and pan around.

Is it this projection that is the issue, or the order in which I am doing things?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "reproject the basemap to this projection", do you mean adding the basemap, which has some coordinate reference system, to an ArcGIS data frame that uses a different CRS (in this case `NAD83 CSRS Statistics Canada Lambert`)? Or has the basemap be reprojected (i.e., with the *Project* tool, which creates a new file in the desired CRS)?

The rest of this answer assumes the first case (which is called on-the-fly projection). From the [ArcGIS help](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/about-editing-data-in-a-different-projection-projecting-on-the-fly-.htm):

> The coordinate system of a data frame in ArcMap can be different from the native coordinate system of the data sources represented by the layers shown in the data frame. In this case, ArcMap projects (on the fly) the features in these layers to the data frame's coordinate system. ArcMap also lets you edit features while they are projected.

**It's not so much the order of doing things or the particular projection you are using as the just fact that on-the-fly reprojection can be slow.**

It's possible that your data is the issue (though I doubt it, as it's already in your desired CRS). You can confirm by turning on just the basemap and panning around then turning on just the data and panning around.

I would predict that the issue is the on-the-fly reprojection of the basemap. If you are using a locally stored basemap, you should be able to make things better by reprojecting it (with the *Project* tool) into `NAD83 Stats Can Lambert`. The idea being to get all that processing out of the way up front, rather than a little bit every time you pan around or zoom.

If your basemap is of the "File > Add Data > Add Basemap..." variety, I am not aware of a good fix. I would probably look into obtaining a basemap that you can store locally (and reproject to match your data). [GeoGratis](https://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geography/topographic-information/free-data-geogratis/11042), from the Government of Canada, is a great resource for basemaps.

OpenStreetMap data can be great for this too. [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/) does regional extracts from OSM for download and then [TileMill](https://blog.mapbox.com/create-a-custom-map-of-your-city-in-30-minutes-with-tilemill-and-openstreetmap-5d9935176d81) can be used to generate raster tiles. This process is actually pretty neat - but it's definitely a lot more work than finding a ready-to-go basemap and is a bit of a pain on a windows machine (at least it used to be).

Using vector basedata (again, projected to `NAD83 Stats Can Lambert`) might be an option also. Again for OSM data, there is the [ArcGIS Editor for OSM](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4533407decd94428817a228cb36964cf) which works a treat for downloading OSM data for a particular area. The municipal and/or provincial government for the study area may have an open data portal which can be a great source of basedata. The main issue with this approach is having to set the symbology for all the different types of data yourself. If you only happen to need a few layers (e.g., roads and rivers), then the vector basedata can be a good way to go.